# How to save all things of a listview in a fragment?

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, android-savedstate

I have a fragment in which I have put a listview which gets its content from internet , When I click a row and come back to the listview it gets data again, but i want to keep last state of listview , how can I do that ?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    list = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.mainList);
    footerView = ((LayoutInflater) G.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
    mainInfoList = new ArrayList<MainInfo>();

    mainInfoAdapter = new AdapterMainInfo(getActivity(), R.id.mainList, mainInfoList);
    list.setAdapter(mainInfoAdapter);
}
```

...

Comment: are you using activity or fragment?

Comment: Use dataModel to store temp data.

Comment: i am using Fragment

Comment: where do you get the data(in the code)?

Comment: then inyour fragment in onViewCreated, check for adapter. like: if(adapter==null){ then fetch data from internet  }else{ adapter.notifydatasetchanged() }

Comment: private void additems() {
        G.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(mainListReq);
    }

Comment: it wont help...

Comment: keep a boolean variable say loaded = false initially.When first time your listview data is loaded make it true.In your onCreate if loaded is false then get your data else  setadapter to it.

Comment: I dont want to save the data in memory or database , is it posibble to not save and then wont reload it ?

Comment: use my method, i am using it and it is working good

Comment: @Divyesh Thank you so muuuuuuuch

Comment: method work for you??

Comment: Yes it works for me

Comment: enjoy..........

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible by two ways:

**1. Fragment transaction type:** This is the best way with no vulnerability.

Use add for fragment transaction rather than replace or remove.

**Fragment1>>(add)>>Fragment2**

In this scenario when you came back from fragment2 to fragment1, it's view will not create again. Because onCreateView will not call again.

**2. Code management**

If you want to use only replace or remove for fragment transaction from fragment1 to fragment2 due to some work that is important for your app.

So do one thing in onCreateView, check for rootview. If root view is null then create new one or leave whatever is happening there.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(mRootView==null){
       mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    }else {
        container.removeView(rootView);
    }
}
```